# Flutter: How can I check if ping / touch / face / whatever is set up on the phone using local_auth package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app and trying to use the local_auth package: https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth

Works great if I have PIN or fingerprint set up but if I don't have anything... Then I have no idea what to do.

I have this code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Is device supported ----> $_isDeviceSupported");
    print("Have biometrics -> $_haveBiometrics");
    print("Biometric authenticated -> $_biometricAuthenticated");
    print("Not available -> $_notAvailable");


    return _notAvailable ? _widgetToShowIfAuthenticated : _isDeviceSupported
        ? _haveBiometrics
            ? _biometricAuthenticated
                ? _widgetToShowIfAuthenticated
                : authenticationPage()
            : _widgetToShowIfAuthenticated
        : authenticationPage();
  }
```

I can check if the device have any of these option. For example can it have a PIN code or fingerprint? -> `_isDeviceSupported`
I can check if it has any biometric authentication -> `_haveBiometrics`

These work great if the phone have PIN or fingerprint. But if the device is able to use these kind of authentication methods, the `_isDeviceSupported` is true, but if I try to authenticate I get an error:

`PlatformException(NotAvailable, Required security features not enabled, null, null)`

And I want to find out that it is `NotAvailable` before I get the exception. At the moment I have this:

```
  void authenticate() async {
    if (!biometricAuthenticated) {
      try {
        biometricAuthenticated = await _auth.authenticate(
          localizedReason: "Please authenticate",
          stickyAuth: true,
          useErrorDialogs: true,
          biometricOnly: false,
        );
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        print(e);
        print("Message: ${e.message}");
        print("Message: ${e.code}");
        if (e.code == "NotAvailable") notAvailable = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see I have to first catch the exception then set the `notAvailable` variable true... This does not seem right. I should check somehow even if the phone is able to use these security methods, are they set up...